# How to create XAML splash screen with PRISM

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, prism, unity-container

I am using PRISM 4.1 with UNITY for my application. I want to display a nice splash screen which will be a xaml window that will show a progress bar. Once all modules are loaded (one of the modules does lengthy database access operation on startup) splash screen should close and shell is shown. I cannot find any sample for this, all samples online use in-built SplashScreen which just points to static image. I want my splash screen to be xaml not just a static image or animated gif.

Comment: I too am looking to implement this exact functionality, so will be keeping an eye on the answers. When I do attempt this, if I find a good way, I'll let you know :)

Comment: @Lukazoid Thanks, for now I have it working with just a png image.

Answer (score 4):

To start your own XAML based Splash screen via the Bootstrapper (in this example he refers to "his own" SplashScreen.xaml based on Window....don't confuse with the in-built SplashScreen class):

- http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Showing_a_Splash_Screen_whilst_initializing_a_WPF_Prism_application.aspx

To start your own XAML based Splash screen Window defined in a Module:

- http://prismsplashscreen.codeplex.com/

To use the in-built SplashScreen class which references a static image as the splash (be aware the splash image is NOT set to Build Type=SplashScreen...it's set to Built Type=Resource....because the resource is referred to in the constructor):

- http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/258644/
- https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=12a8b70137345033&sc=documents&id=12A8B70137345033%21147

Comment: This one is using in-built splashscreen with static image

Answer (score 0):

Try this example : Prism Splash Screen Module

This project is intended to demonstrade a neat way for developers to add splash screen to their Prism based applications. The main features are:1. The splash screen is encapsulated in a Prism module, which can be loaded explicitly by bootstraper code or implicitly loaded fro...

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp_Free_Code/Application/Download_Prism_Splash_Screen_Module.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.